# Select from multiple tables which ends on

Tags: mysql, select

I have multiple tables which looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%SYSTEMNAME%_bookings` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `begins` datetime NOT NULL,
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

Where %SYSTEMNAME% could be anything and there can be x amount of tables.

I would like to be able to get a list of every entry (a select statement) in all of the tables, the reason behind this is to make statistics about how many bookings on each day and so on)

How can this be done, it's a bit of my normal sql stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t think that you can achieve this with an simple sql query.
I would create a stored procedure with a cursor on that [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html):

```
SHOW TABLES FROM yourDB LIKE '%_bookings';
```

Answer (score -1):

No, its not normal. You cannot specify a variable table name in a single query. You'll either have to use `UNION` between multiple `SELECT` queries, provided the tables have or you `SELECT` same number of fields from all tables like

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM tbl1
UNION
SELECT d, e, f FROM tbl2
UNION
SELECT g, h, i FROM tbl3
...
```

or use multiple `SELECT` in prepared statements like

```
SET $table_name = (SELECT tbl_name FROM system_tables LIMIT 1, @OFFSET);
SET @s = CONCAT('select * from ', @table_name); 

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```